# Refactor duplicated code in gradle task "type: Copy"

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

A gradle project contains several similar task `type:Copy` and some of them require additional checks.

```
task copyPackage1(type: Copy) {
    from buildPackage1
    into "/pkgs/"
    eachFile {
        if (it.relativePath.getFile(destinationDir).exists()) {
            throw new GradleException("Probably version was no updated. File exists: " + it)
        }
    }
}
...
task copyPackage2(type: Copy) {
    from buildPackage2
    into "/pkgs/"
    eachFile {
        if (it.relativePath.getFile(destinationDir).exists()) {
            throw new GradleException("Probably version was no updated. File exists: " + it)
        }
    }
}
```

How it is possible to refactor duplicated checks and specify same target directory for all similar tasks (but not all `Copy` tasks)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either implement this with a custom Gradle plugin (as suggested in [this similar question](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/best-way-to-extend-and-reconfigure-built-in-tasks/7316/8) on Gradle forum), or use simple Groovy method to create and configure your tasks, as follows:

```
// define a "task creator" method 
ext.createCopyToPkgTask = { String taskName ,  String fromDir ->
    return project.tasks.create(taskName, Copy.class){
        from fromDir
        into "/pkgs"
        eachFile {
            if (it.relativePath.getFile(destinationDir).exists()) {
                throw new GradleException("Probably version was no updated. File exists: " + it)
            }
        }
    }
}

/* declare your similar tasks using the creator method above */
createCopyToPkgTask("copyPackage1","buildPackage1")
createCopyToPkgTask("copyPackage2","buildPackage2")
// ...
```

Comment: There is need a small update: `String fromDir` -> `fromDir`; `"buildPackage1"` -> `buildPackage1`, because it is not String, but task.