# Gradle - Chaining test tasks with `--tests` filter

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle, testng, gradlew

I have been at this for a few days now, let's say I have a `build.gradle` as follows:

```
ext.createRunIntegrationTestsTask = { String taskName ,  String buildPlatform ->
    return project.tasks.create(taskName, Test.class) {
        dependsOn buildPlatform
        [...]
    }
}

def Platforms = ["A", "B"]
for (platform in Platforms) {
    println "Creating task: runIntegrationTestsPlatform$platform"
    createRunIntegrationTestsTask("runIntegrationTestsPlatform$platform", "buildPlatform$platform")
}
    
task runIntegrationTest(type: Test) {
    dependsOn 'runIntegrationTestPlatformA'
    dependsOn 'runIntegrationTestPlatformB'
}
```

I want to be able to run the following command with the tests filter:

```
gradlew :runIntegrationTest --tests "com.somestuff.methodTest"
```

For some reason when the above command runs, it does not pass the tests filter to `runIntegrationTestPlatformA` and `runIntegrationTestPlatformB` task. Both the `runIntegrationTestPlatform...` tasks run the whole suite of integration tests.

The current behavior I get is for `runIntegrationTestPlatform...` tasks to run the whole integration test suite for the specified platform and `runIntegrationTest` to run the integration test suite for all platforms.

But, when I pass the `--tests` filter to `runIntegrationTest` task, it does not get propagated to the chained tasks, i.e. `runIntegrationTestPlatformA` and `runIntegrationTestPlatformB`. Instead, it runs the whole integration test suite for both platforms. I want `runIntegrationTestPlatformA` and `runIntegrationTestPlatformB` to use the tests filter passed to `runIntegrationTest` to only run the specified integration tests.

Is there a way to get `runIntegrationTestPlatformA` and `runIntegrationTestPlatformB` to run from `runIntegrationTest` with the `--tests` filter.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Additional Sources:

1. [Refactor duplicated code in gradle task "type: Copy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56185430/refactor-duplicated-code-in-gradle-task-type-copy)